# iOS simulator somehow broken with rotation and controls placement

Tags: ios, delphi, simulator

When I decide iOS simulator should show anything but normal iPhone, something very odd happens.

If e.g. iPad is placed landscape left to right, it places content layout all wrong. This also happens in its own iOS before any apps is run. See screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Tried to **reset content and settings**, but still no luck:

[image]
[image]

Comment: reset the simulator and try again.

Comment: a bit offtopic, but... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-my-mac

Comment: @Tarek no luck resetting content and setings. (TThat was what you meant, right?) See new screenshots

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the link on taking screenshots on Mac :)

Comment: You are talking about **iPad** and show us pictures of **iPhone** simulator? Your simulator shows retina iPhone 4" with 1136x640px. What is the actual resolution of your MacBook? Do you have switch on the rotation lock on simulator?

Comment: @SirRufo Problem same with all. However, I see what you mean now about rotate lock. (To my knowledge I did not have it on since I tested earlier on normal where it worked, but I must have made a mistake. Only sensible explanation. I will return when I am infront of it again soon.) The Macbook screen resolution is probably too small, but I figured here was a way for simulator to let me see it anyhow. (Maybe by scrolling the view or something like that.)

Comment: For reference, I now see there's a **scale** option in the iOS simulator which really solved the issue for me I think in the sense I now can see everything.... The other thing with rotation seems to have resolved itself as well now. I will accept answer from Tarek and SirRufo. Whichever you think.

Comment: @Tom You can also post your own answer, since you're the one who found the solution. Since we may have never used this particular simulator, you might be the most applicable person to answer this.